# alternate button text automatically without click

Tags: jquery, html

I would like alternate between 2 pieces of text on a button in 2 sec intervals. This is NOT a click event. I just want the button to rotate between 'click here' and 'download'. This is what Im trying with no luck:

```
<div class="assetClass customButton1_1Div" id="download_btn1">
<input type="button" class="customButton1_1" name="button1_1" value="click here" title="download_btn1" />
</div>

setInterval(toggle, 2000);
function toggle() {
document.getElementByName("button1_1").value = "download";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var cnt=0, arr = ['Click Here','Download'];
setTimeout(toggle, 1500);

function toggle() {
  $('.btn').val(arr[cnt]);
  cnt = (cnt > 0) ? 0 : 1;
  setTimeout(toggle, 1500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="assetClass customButton1_1Div" id="download_btn1">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Download" />
</div>
```

Note that setInterval has certain drawbacks compared with a recursive setTimeout:

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern

Comment: is there a reason you need setTimeout twice?

Comment: The first setTimeout delays the first swap, the 2nd delays each additional. You could simply start the function by calling it but it would immediately change the button text, possibly flashing the text. The setTimeout inside the function is definitely necessary, as that creates the delay between changing button text. But feel free to experiment with it. [Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a3mc2j3/) *(they are a bit easier to fiddle around with)*

Comment: Do browse the linked article at bottom as Eric does a fantastic job explaining the downside of setInterval

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByName is plural and returns a collection.

**Plain JS:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var but = document.getElementsByName("button1_1")[0];
    but.value = but.value == "click here" ? "download" : "click here";
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="assetClass customButton1_1Div" id="download_btn1">
  <input type="button" class="customButton1_1" name="button1_1" value="click here" title="download_btn1" />
</div>
```

**jQuery adding the alternate value to the button:**

```js
$(function() {
  var $but = $("input[name='button1_1']").first();
  var showVal = true,butVal = [$but.val(), $but.data("alternate")];
  setInterval(function() {
    showVal=!showVal;
    $but.val(butVal[+showVal]);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="assetClass customButton1_1Div" id="download_btn1">
  <input type="button" class="customButton1_1" name="button1_1" value="Click here" title="download_btn1" data-alternate="Download" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery and altered the toggle function to check current value; 
If it doesn't match "download", it sets the value to "download". If it does match, it sets the value to "click here".

https://jsfiddle.net/tg7ks727/

```
    $(function(){
    setInterval(ToggleText, 2000);
});

  function ToggleText() {
    var currentValue = $('input').attr("value");
    console.log(currentValue);
    if(currentValue != "download"){
       $('input').attr("value", "download");
    }
    else {
      $('input').attr("value", "click here");
    }
    }
```